# 'What a good parent should do is spending time with their children' is wrong

Tags: gerunds, to-infinitive

> What a good parent should also do is spending time with their children.

The model answer is to change 'spending' to 'to spend'. To me, spending and to spend are the noun phrase, the former being a gerund while the latter being an to-infinitive strucutre. I don't understand why the gerund is not used correctly.

Comment: *Spending* is wrong. And I’d say that even better than *to spend* is simply *spend*. Compare, “When I need to relax, what I do is **play** the piano.” Or “If you want a lower-fat version of the recipe, what you can do is **reduce** the amount of butter.”

Comment: Hm... I'm not able to articulate the answer well, but sentence order matters here. "Swimming is what I like to do" = OK. "What I like to do is swimming" = not idiomatic. Even "What I like to do is to swim" is clunky, like the sentence you gave; "I like to swim" would be more comfortable.

Comment: The word **do** determines the choice.   What a parent **likes** is **spending** time with their children.  What a good parent should **do** is **spend** time with their children.

Comment: What a good parent should **be doing** is **spending** time with their children.

Comment: @TimR, your explanation is quite good. I encourage you to make it an answer.

Comment: @TimR: Only, is not the word "should" what really determines the choice? Should do. Should spend. Should be doing. It needs to be followed by an infinitive, no preposition.

Comment: @MariaA.  **should** in the main clause doesn't determine the choice of verb in the complement clause.  **should** there determines the form of the lexical verb in the main clause only.  We can have **should do** and **should be doing**.

Comment: I should probably  add that  **should have been doing** is also valid..

Comment: @TimR: I see that now. So, in the example "What a good parent should (do / like / be doing /  be liking / like doing / should have been liking doing etc.) is....", the second clause would be, respectively, "...spend / spending /  spend / spending / spend / spend etc.  time", right?

Comment: @MariaA. I think your list alignment is off.  be do**ing** -> spend**ing**

Answer (score 4):

With sentences of this structure: "What someone [verb] is [non-finite complement clause]",  the form of [verb] determines the form of the verb in the complement clause.

It will always be a non-finite nominal form of the verb in the complement clause because the verb form must be able to occupy the nominal slot created by the interrogative *pronoun* "What".

> What is he doing?
>
> -- Taking the baby to the pediatrician.

not

> What is he doing?
>
> -- *Takes the baby to the pediatrician. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Finite verb **takes** (3rd person singular present) cannot fill the slot created by *What*, but a non-finite form can fill that slot.

So, on to your good parent examples.

> What a good parent should **do** is **spend** time with their children.

**do** expresses the notion  *perform (generic) act*, and so we need a non-finite verb form that expresses the idea of "perform (specific) act", and that form is the unmarked infinitive, **spend**.

> What a good parent should be **doing** is **spending** time with their children.

There, because of **doing**, we need a non-finite verb form that expresses action-in-progress or habitual action, and that form is the verb's participial form, **spending** .